# "Leave nothing (left) behind"

Tags: meaning, redundancy, lyrics

In the lyrics for "[What are you waiting for](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/disturbed/whatareyouwaitingfor.html)" from Disturbed, there is the line:

> Leave nothing left behind

I'm debating whether "left" is superfluous and here only for rythm, or if the expression "left behind" that forms adds meaning to the sentence compared to "leave nothing behind".

Is the phrase correct as-is, and does removing "left" change the meaning slightly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on on the [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/) learner's definitions of *leave* and *leave behind* the word "left" in the phrase:

> Leave nothing left behind

appears to be superfluous.

For reference, the Collins learner's definition for *leave* is:

> *leave*
>
> 2. *verb*
>
> If you leave an institution, group, or job, you permanently stop attending that institution, being a member of that group, or doing that job.

The Collins learners' definition for *leave behind* is:

> *leave behind*
>
> 1. *phrasal verb*
>
> If you leave someone or something behind, you go away permanently from them.

Thus based on these definitions the term "left" in the phrase:

> Leave nothing left behind

Is superfluous.

Hope this is helpful!